# Excel Automation Error Run-time Error 440- Autocorrecting Outlook Appointment .Start

Tags: excel, outlook, excel-2010, vba

I have been searching how to fix this problem for sometime. It's hard to find specific answers without having to dive deep into VBA for outlook, which I would do if I have to.

I have a calendar update macro that should be adding appointments to our outlook calendar. I inherited the code, and just copied it and pasted it over, making some minor tweaks as far as cell references. The codes is below:

```
Sub CreateNewItems()

Dim dimnum As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim objOL   'As Outlook.Application
Dim objApt 'As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objNamespace
Dim strFolderName
Dim objCalendar
Dim objInbox
Dim pctCompl As Single
Const olMeeting = 1
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Const olAppointmentItem = 1 '1 = Appointment
'do not display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'do not update screen
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Create new Undergrad info session events on Outlook Calendar
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Windows("WebScraper.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Calendar Info Sess. Bridge").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Range("B2").Select
ws.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
dimnum = Selection.count

ws.Range("B2").Select
num = 0
Do Until num = dimnum
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Finds your Inbox
    Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'Gets the parent of your Inbox which gives the Users email
    strFolderName = objInbox.Parent
    Set objCalendar =     objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName).Folders("Calendar").Folders("Undergrad TNRB")

    Set objApt = objCalendar.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    With objApt
        .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
        .Location = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        .start = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ActiveCell.Value
        .End = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Text & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .Save
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    num = num + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

From what I can tell, the problem is that in the `With` block, it should be `.Start` instead of `.start`. Unfortunately, every time I try to capitalize, VBA autocorrects back to `.start`. I do have some other subs that run before this code, but I removed any instance where I used the word "start", whether it was capitalized or not, commented, or executable code, so I'm not creating any variable unknowingly that this line would be trying to reference (as far as I can tell). I thought it might be that `.Start` is an VBA defined function, but I don't know enough to know if that's true, or what the needed convention would be to get this to save the appointment to outlook.

You can see that I am getting the number of rows in the sheet in the first couple of lines, and then I repeat the `Do` loop for every row of the sheet. Just as is intuitive in the `With` block, 9 columns to the right is a subject line for the appointment, 4 columns to the right is the location of the appointment, the active column is the date of the appointment starting, the next column over is the date the appointment ends (all events start and end on the same date), the column 2 to the right is the start time, and the column 3 to the right is the end time.

Comment: Do you have any Module/Function/Procedure named as `Start`. If not, then just type `Dim Start` at the beginning of the procedure and press enter. Then delete that line. Now check

Comment: It seems like that was a good idea--all of the `.start` lines changed to `.Start`. Still, when I run through that line of code, I get a "Run-time error '440': Automation error".

Comment: Now I am confused... Are you getting a Syntax Error or an Automation Error?

Comment: I also tried `Dim Start As String` and that didn't work either. I wonder why you would have to define Start and not Subject, Location, End, or Save.

Comment: No you do not have to define that. I suggested that so that the Capitalization could return :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that vba can give you an error message that says 'syntax error.' I thought it was an error in my syntax, which is why I said syntax error. VBA is actually giving me an automation error. I don't know what that means.

Comment: Your code works for me. Ensure that `1` "Undergrad TNRB" folder exists `2` You are passing a valid time to Start and End. Example : 18:00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108972/discussion-between-james-marriott-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was running through the code, the time columns (columns 1 to the right and 3 to the right) were narrow, and visually these columns showed #s (just like excel does when the column isn't fully expanded). For some reason, the code was pulling the #s, rather than the actual value. It may have something to do with the .Text, but when I used .Value, it still wasn't working. So, if anyone else has this problem, try Columns.EntireColumn.Autofit on the columns that are too narrow that you're trying to pull values from.